# See variable as byte

Tags: variable-definitions, memory

I see variable `v` is occupying 112 bytes of my RAM.

```
v = {3, 5, 7}; ByteCount[v]
112
```

Then how to see the content of the 112 bytes?

I tried some codes like `BinaryRead`, `Read[..,Bytes]`,.. but failed.

Comment: See some interesting details for [`ByteCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html#21088)

Comment: Thank you, but I want more detail..

Comment: Of course. I understand that. That's why I only left it as a comment :)

Comment: I don't think you can. If you're interested in what takes up all those bytes beyond the 24 needed to store 3 machine integers then the [internal implementation notes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html) have some details.